# TeXmaker PDF viewer blurry

Tags: texmaker

I am using TeXmaker on a MacBook Retina with an additional external display. The documents displayed in the PDF viewer while on the external display are very grainy/blurry and hard to read, while they are completely fine on the MacBook screen and when opening the produced PDF with another software. I didn't find anything related to this online.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: Please help people to help you by posting a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. Have you tried adding `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` to your preamble?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and found a work around. Open texmaker on your laptop's screen and adjust the size of the program window so that it fits the external screen (or your needs). If you than drag the texmaker window to the external screen and do not (!) resize the texmaker window, the internal pdf viewer looks normal.

As you might have an external screen larger than the laptop screen, you have to fiddle a bit to first adjust the size of the program window on your laptop screen, but it is worth it. The good thing is that resizing the pdf size within the viewer is fine.

Comment: If that's  the case  I would  recommend  to use  an other  pdfreader,  you'll need one,  which does not block writing on the file and updates  it when you compile. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43057/macosx-pdf-viewer-automatic-reload-on-file-modification

Comment: Hey, I tried this and it did not work.  The text looks fine on my laptop's screen regardless of window size, and always looks gritty on the external monitor also regardless of window size.

Answer (score 1):

Don't remember where I read this, but tried MacOsx 10.6 64 bits version and it works without any work around. Apparently MacOsx 10.7 64 bits is the problem. Give it a try.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://tex.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/93954)

Comment: @StefanPinnow But if an other version solves the problem, why shouldn't this be a valid answer?

Comment: @samcarter because downgrading to an outdated OS is not a solution. it's a workaround at best. and the new MacBooks aren't supported by the older OS. if at all, a VM running 10.6.x could be used.

Comment: @naphaneal I understood the answer as in using the version of TeXmaker for 10.6 and not using another OS.