# Built-in PDF viewer of TexMaker is blurry

Tags: texmaker

I am using TeXmaker because it has the preview to the right.

However, upon installing into my new laptop, I've noticed that the preview of the internal PDF viewer was quite blurry. I would like to know how to improve the quality of the render. (screenshot below)

[image: The PDF is blurry! Also the icons!]

You can also see that the GUI icons are blurry. I am not sure if it is related to that.

I've looked at the following existing questions and I would reason out why they didn't help:

- [TeXmaker PDF viewer blurry](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172266/texmaker-pdf-viewer-blurry). I tried this and this did not help. Also, the instructions were for a MacBook and I'm running Arch.
- [Texmaker GUI is messy with high resolution screen](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/333103/texmaker-gui-is-messy-with-high-resolution-screen). While this might be related to the GUI issue, this does not address the blurry PDF preview.

I would prefer a solution that actually fixes the TexMaker issue. I'm guessing here, but maybe there's a way to give a custom command to the Built-In PDF Viewer which tells it to render itself in a higher quality.

However, if no fix can be found, I would be open to suggestions on which other TeX editor would have a built-in viewer as well. I installed TeXstudio and I run into the same problem of blurry PDFs.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For me this solution from pmassat worked: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/486280/213

Comment: Similar issue in TeXstudio in KDE with scaling enabled: Upgrading to a later version worked. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1390311/how-to-fix-blurred-pdf-preview-in-texstudio-under-fractional-scaling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok. So I solved it. Sort of.

I was using KDE and it has this "Scale Display" option. I had it at 1.3 and I guess this feature wasn't so compatible with TexMaker. I set it to 1 and things got fixed.

Comment: I would like to know who to report this to. KDE or TexMaker? Or both. And how.

Comment: It not a problem its a feature as per previous answers down to using small pixels on big screens it is controlled by Microsoft true type on windows aggravated by QT scalling on all platforms and the application not adjusting for ever global user combination possible.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think I understand what you're saying. First of all, I would like to know how this issue is related with Microsoft True Type fonts as I'm using Linux. Second, I don't understand how this can be a font issue when opening the compiled PDF on another application works fine. Third, I don't understand how this is a feature if it prevents the user from enjoying an intended feature. One could say it doesn't support compatibility with KDE, but I would not go as far to calling it a feature.

Comment: I agree it not a desirable feature , my comment about windows is for other users since Texmaker is cross platform and currently I have it on one windows screen at 100% zoom where its doing my eyes in since it was launched at 1.5 scale so to be running Texmaker in this state is an issue though I personally could change many setting to clear it but then other QT apps would be affected  and need resetting

Comment: With Windows 10 this got me to the solution: I extend my window from Laptop to second screen. The Laptop screen it's fine and on external it's blurry. Switching the scaling in monitor-settings down to 100% did the trick. Though this means that now the symbols and text on my laptop are quite small...

Comment: Update: You can have the texmaker PDF preview in a second window (in texmaker options -> configuration -> tick off "integrate into texmaker interface". exact naming could differ as I don't have it in English). 
Now I write on my external screen and have the preview on my laptop non-blurry and keep standard scaling. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 7):

This worked

- open Explorer,
- search Start menu,
- find application (e.g., TexMaker)
- right-click the application name, select 'Properties'
- Make sure runs in Admin mode
- In the 'Properties' window, select the 'Compatibility' tab.
- Under 'Settings', click 'Change high DPI settings'
- select (check) "Use this setting to fix ..."  choose option "I open this program"
- select (check) "Override high DPI scaling ..." choose option "System"
- Restart TexMaker
- Run pdfviewer in 'built-in viewer' mode

Comment: I had the same problem on Windows 11 and this worked perfectly to solve the blurry pdf viewer issue.

Comment: It works for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled quite a lot with thin on my Mac which had an external high resolution display (Apple cinema 30"). The way I solved it:

- navigate to Applications texmaker
- right click on texmaker, show package contents
- open Contents and find the info.plist
- open it with an editor or xcode
- change the high resolution capable entry to NO
- save and restart texmaker

hope it helps someone