# Texmaker's built-in PDF viewer is blurry

Tags: texmaker, viewers

I have the same problem described here [Built-in PDF viewer of TexMaker is blurry](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/473948/built-in-pdf-viewer-of-texmaker-is-blurry), but none of the suggested fixes worked for me (some of them are not applicable as I am on a MacBook Pro running macOS Ventura rather than Windows). I have also tried changing the high resolution capable entry in the .plist file: the setting "False" looks better on the external display, but horrendous on the built-in MacBook Pro display, and vice versa. The problem does not occur with any other apps I am using. I even downloaded Texstudio to confirm that the issue is specific to Texmaker. I am using the latest version 5.1.3 available here: https://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/

Comment: Viewing pdf's in Apple's Preview or Safari has often been blurry for me since (about, I've forgotten the exact OS version) Mountain Lion.  I assume they share the same utility, perhaps texmaker also uses it.  Firefox, Chrome, and Acrobat Reader are fine.

Comment: I don't think this is the case because Texmaker can be configured such that the PDF is displayed in a viewer other than the embedded/built-in one, and if I choose Preview the PDF looks fine on either screen. I simply prefer my workflow with the side-by-side view using the built-in/embedded PDF viewer, which is why it'd be great if that could be made to work on either screen as well.