# skim cannot reload file after auctex preview-latex

Tags: emacs, auctex, preview

I am using emacs+skim to preview latex on macs, and I use auctex preview-latex from time to time. the problem is, after I run `C-c C-p C-d` in emacs to preview entire document, the pdf file is now deleted, and skim show a bunch of formulas (as Sumatra does on Windows). Then I recompile and run `C-c C-v` to see file in skim, but skill still shows a bunch of formulas in separate pages. While in Sumatra, it shows immediately the newly compiled pdf file, despite that it was deleted a while ago due to preivew-latex. Is there a way to fix this on mac?

p.s.

This seems only to happen when the entire document is previewed in emacs, for example, `C-c C-p C-e` does not cause this problem.

At first skim ask permission to revert for every newly generated pdf file, but the "secret preference" mentioned in the [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43057/macosx-pdf-viewer-automatic-reload-on-file-modification) resolves the issue.

Comment: I just close Skim programmatically and open a new pdf, because I found a bug in Skim a few months ago -- although I cannot remember right now exactly what it was.  However, that may be a non-AUCTeX solution -- I have both options.  Here is a link to my setup -- I don't have any issues, but I don's use preview -- I just print a final pdf and if I don't like it, I revise the LaTeX source and generate a new pdf:  Here is the first link:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/22746845/2112489  and here is the second link:  http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/156617/26911

Comment: @lawlist, thanks! I have no problem generating pdf, neither do I have to kill skim in terminal, there is a revert option in the menu list. However, as a lazy person, I am curious if this could be avoided, since Sumatra has no such problem.

Comment: There are two Skim options to revert -- the non-hidden option in the Preferences (i.e., "Check for file changes" under the `Sync` menu), which probably gives you the yes / no option, and that is why you (like all of us) have Googled the hidden option:  `defaults write -app Skim SKAutoReloadFileUpdate -boolean true`  It sounds like you need to program in a close the current window on Skim, however, I haven't researched the Applescript equivalent (just close the entire program).  I'll add to my todo-list a close window Applescript if no one resolves this for you.

Comment: I'll need to pick it up again in the next few days (it's bedtime here in L.A.), but here is the applescript to close a window -- the idea is that you get rid of the window that contains an error without closing the entire application:  `(defun test () (interactive) (let ((script (concat "set myWindowTitle to \"envelope.pdf\"\n" "tell application \"System Events\"\n" "tell application \"Skim\" to close (every window whose name contains myWindowTitle)\n" "end tell\n" ))) (start-process "osascript-getinfo" nil "osascript" "-e" script)))`  Of course, we'll substitute envelope.pdf for the real one.

Comment: I've incorporated the `close-skim-window` applescript into a non-AUCTeX solution in the `elisp` function `latexmk` in the following link: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/156617/26911  The original poster could (in theory) use that type of mechanism to close the window of the improperly displayed *.pdf so that a new window gets generated during the compilation process.  If someone would like to turn that into an AUCTeX solution for the original poster, please feel free to use my idea.

Comment: Here is an applescript that may serve to Revert the *.pdf; however, Revert is greyed-out for me so I couldn't test it -- it works with Open, so it probably works with Revert (when not greyed-out) -- go ahead and give it a whirl:  `(defun revert-pdf () (interactive) (let ((script (concat "tell application \"Skim\"\n" "activate\n" "tell application \"System Events\" to tell process \"Skim\"\n" "click (menu item 1 where its name starts with \"Revert\") of menu 1 of menu bar item \"File\" of menu bar 1\n" "end tell\n" "end tell"))) (start-process "osascript-getinfo" nil "osascript" "-e" script)))`