# MacOSX Alternative to UltiSnips, and tools to write mathematics notes in LaTeX faster

Tags: vim, macos

For writing textual content and mathematical formulas in LaTeX, I use Vim. I use Vim for writing code, markdown, and LaTeX. I have just recently read an [article](https://castel.dev/post/lecture-notes-1/) by a Mathematics PhD student, Gilles Castel, and I would most certainly like to adopt his workflow on LaTeX, Vim, a PDF viewer, [Inkscape](https://castel.dev/post/lecture-notes-2/), and a snippet manager for Vim like [UltiSnips](https://github.com/SirVer/ultisnips). Adopting this LaTeX system will allow myself to enjoy using LaTeX, spell check on impulse, comfortably take mathematics notes and figures as fast as the lecturer speaks, and annotating pdf documents that use LaTeX in order to write comments alongside a pdf document. The increase in speed does not compromise quality, as seen below: [image: Example of his large repository of over 1700 pages of notes]
<sub>(source: [castel.dev](https://castel.dev/static/ba66c52b01c8fe6b31c97af52b5eb7f7/359dd/ca1.png))</sub>
I am looking for (a) a MacOS-based alternative to UltiSnips and (b) a pdf viewer that supports LaTeX.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Let me see if I may summarize your posting: You are looking for (a) a MacOS-based alternative to UltiSnips and (b) a pdf viewer that "supports LaTeX". Is this about right? Please advise.

Comment: Yes, this is correct

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not familiar with UltiSnips. Are you familiar with the MacOS [command]-[shift]-[4] method for grabbing screenshots? If that's not sufficient for you, which additional functionality are you looking to get?

Comment: Yes, I am familiar. I am looking for a snippet (a short reusable piece of text that can be triggered by some other text. i.e. I type "sign" and press tab to expand into a signature). Or snippets can be dynamical: for instance, he gives an example of typing "today" and pressing Tab, which replaces the word "today" with the current date. I would like to use snippets to write LaTeX faster, as more "complex" snippets save time. Things like inline and display math, environments, subscripts, and fractions. There are more examples in his post, if you would like to take a look?

Comment: Just looking now, I see that UltiSnips is a snippet "manager", and, using Vim, you can download packages of snippets. A snippet manager would be nice, however if there isn't one, or if it is to tedious to find, then I can go without.

Comment: Castels setup works without modification on macOS, you only need [skim](https://skim-app.sourceforge.io/index.html) if you want to enable synctex. There are also [tons of other snippet packages](https://vimawesome.com/?q=tag:snippets) for vim, if you don't like ultisnips (check out [luasnip](https://github.com/L3MON4D3/LuaSnip) for neovim)

Comment: I feel the question of snippet managers is off-topic for here, the question and answers wouldn't really change whether the OP was asking about using snippets for LaTeX, another programming language, or prose. It may better suited to https://vi.stackexchange.com/ or https://apple.stackexchange.com/ for vim or MacOS respectively. As to viewers, they just need to open PDFs, but presumably you're really asking the same as [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43057).

Answer (score 0):

On the Mac, TextExpander and Typinator are two popular snippet managers.  Keyboard Maestro and Launchbar are automation apps that do much more than just snippets, but also work well for snippets.  Personally, I lean towards Typinator. It is reasonably priced, frequently updated, allows you to associate specifics sets of replacements to specific apps and has a decent set of what you might call “smart” replacement options also (today’s date, whatever in the clipboard, etc.)

Comment: I have heard of Keyboard Maestro and TextExpander, however I haven't come to use them yet. Of the news I have heard from it, it seems to be an incredibly powerful app. I must ask, is it a steep learning curve to using it? I came across these applications through a podcast by the name of "The Automators", where I have found many great tips, tricks and applications to use (and that I have used) through time

Comment: If you want an open source alternative to TextExpander and Typinator, try [espanso](https://espanso.org)