# In what ways are TeXStudio and Vim-LaTeX better than each other? And am I going too deep into the rabbit hole of packages/plugins/add-ons in LaTeX?

Tags: texstudio, mac, vim-latex

I have installed TeXStudio and Vim-LaTeX and am conflicted as to which the better option is. As you can tell, I am new to LaTeX and I have only just needed it as a mandatory text editor for my Masters Degree. As a 21 year old, I have only a few weeks ago migrated to LaTeX, and a powerful source of inspiration I currently am using is a few somewhat dated blog posts on the domain https://castel.dev, click here see my recent [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/633599/macosx-alternative-to-ultisnips-and-tools-to-write-mathematics-notes-in-latex-f). It talks about how to take notes in mathematics lectures (while keeping up) using LaTeX and Vim (and a figure drawing application by the name of “Inkscape”), more specifically by using snippets in Vim. As you would know, LaTeX used to take far longer than the average lecture to compile and create, however there are ways to speed up the process, while retaining quality, understanding, and overall pleasure while using a LaTeX editor. I would very much like to know; am I going too deep into the rabbit hole of packages/plugins/add-ons? Or am I on the right path to enjoying using LaTeX for the rest of my career? I am using a Mac. My snippets come from Keyboard Maestro.

Comment: your question is like asking whether you should drive a ford or a vw. it all depends. just use an editor that you like, it makes no difference to Tex. personally I have used Emacs since 1987 and use the same editor for Tex, XML, c, python... but I wouldn't necessarily recommend that setup to a new user who may want a latex specific IDE

Comment: I think this is opinion based. I use a simple graphical text editor with syntax highlighting and an embedded terminal for LaTeX and I am happy with it, no snippets, no hotkeys for compilation, no synctex, nothing - but that's just me.